# JSONAPI Singular Resource

Tags: rest, json-api

What is the correct way to access a singleton, or resource that is always singular in a restful JSONAPI?

I need to get settings so I have this currently...

1. `/api/v1/settings/user-settings`

Is this correct, or does everything need to be accessed with an id like this...

2. `/api/v1/settings/1/user-settings/1`

If I don't have the ids then how would a patch work?

Comment: are the settings specific to a user? it seems like it would be better nested under the user in that case (ie `/api/v1/user/:user_id/settings`)

Comment: @jdubjdub No, they are not specific per user.

Comment: so... who accesses this endpoint? what's it do? seems like maybe you can just get away with this by not nesting settings (eg `/api/v1/user-settings/1`)